# Implementing OnDraw method on static layout view

Tags: java, android

I want to implement `onDraw()` method for layout I have customized in Android Studio. I know how to do this with custom view, but I want to do this with my customized view and can't get info about this on the internet.
This is the code for layout:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);

        //layoutMain.addView(mCustomDrawableView);
        //setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);
        //mCustomDrawableView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

The custom drawable view:

```
class CustomDrawableView extends View
{
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        int width = 300;
        int height = 50;

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is i can choose only one view: static with no OnDraw() or dynamic with OnDraw() but without all my buttons/sliders and other elements. Can i combine them and implement main OnDraw() ?

```
        02-06 19:33:49.793    1823-1823/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cepp.myapplication2/com.example.cepp.myapplication2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.example.cepp.myapplication2.CustomDrawableView
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.example.cepp.myapplication2.CustomDrawableView
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
                at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
                at com.example.cepp.myapplication2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:98)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.cepp.myapplication2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:98)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: call `super.onDraw(canvas);` as the first line in your `onDraw`

Comment: thanks seiterm i updated the question to specify the problem, please reread.

Comment: What do you mean you can "choose only one view"? Is there a reason you don't add your custom view to the layout in xml?

Comment: mean i can design my view with all buttons and elements in android studio. but i do not know how to implement OnDraw() method on that. Or i can create my custom BLANK view with OnDraw() method without my designed elements and draw all elements programatically. i maybe in error so please point me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never place the view in the activity. Treat you custom view just like any other View and put it in the layout

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <!--Add this line or the custom view will push these off the screen-->
        android:layout_parentTop="true"
        <!--  ************************ -->
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"/>

    <com.you.yourapp.CustomDrawableView  <!--com.you.yourapp is a stand in for the package name for your apk-->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="+@id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then it will behave less or more like and `ImageView`

EDIT 2:
That pattern is usually an error in the `View` code. Look at the Priview (all the way to the right in Android Studio, when you have the xml file open). If the view is ok, it will show up in the preview. If it isn't it will tell you where the exceptions are.

Comment: i posted my xml to answer, i am beginner with android so please can you edit it and show me where i should place this?

Comment: faults with error =( 02-06 19:33:49.793    1823-1823/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cepp.myapplication2/com.example.cepp.myapplication2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.example.cepp.myapplication2.CustomDrawableView

Comment: Please add the whole stack trace to your question.

Comment: added whole stacktrace